# Find control of master page working in code behind but not in javascript in content page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, master-pages, findcontrol

I am using vb.net with framework 4.0 ; I am trying to access an asp panel in master page from my content page. In code behind this is working in a button click:

```
CType(Me.Master.FindControl("PanelMsg"), Panel).Visible = True
```

Now I am trying to make the same thing but in client side of my content page:

```
window.onload = test;

 function test() {
     var pan = document.getElementById('<%=CType(Me.Master.FindControl("PanelMsg"), Panel) %>');
     // var pan = document.getElementById('<%=(Master.FindControl("PanelMsg")).ClientID %>');
     alert(pan);
 }
```

pan is null in both cases. How can I resolve this issue in order to make pan visible and change its value?

Comment: why not select it with jquery ? like this $('[id*="PanelMsg"]');

Comment: @sriram I am calling my panel in master page from content page, how could it be possible to use only this: `$('[id*="PanelMsg"]');`

Comment: check out jquery partial id selector

Comment: @sriram it is returning [Object Object] but .val() is undefined